# installing paramiko on Windows

Tags: python, windows, paramiko

This may sound like a repeated question on SF, but I could not find a clear answer to it, yet.So.
I installed Paramiko 1.7 with "setup.py install" command and while running the demo.py program, I got this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\fixavier\Desktop\paramiko-1.7\demos\demo.py", line 33, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from transport import randpool, SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 32, in <module>
    from paramiko import util
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 31, in <module>
    from paramiko.common import *
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\paramiko\common.py", line 99, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util.randpool import PersistentRandomPool, RandomPool
ImportError: No module named Crypto.Util.randpool
```

I'm getting this error even after installing PyCrypto 2.1.
On running test.py(which comes with the installation), I got the following error -

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\fixavier\Desktop\pycrypto-2.0.1\pycrypto-2.0.1\test.py", line 18, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util import test
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\fixavier\Desktop\pycrypto-2.0.1\pycrypto-2.0.1\build/lib.win32-2.6\Crypto\Util\test.py", line 17, in <module>
    import testdata
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\fixavier\Desktop\pycrypto-2.0.1\pycrypto-2.0.1\test\testdata.py", line 450, in <module>
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
ImportError: cannot import name AES
```

I don't have the confidence to go ahead and install AES after all this, for all I know I may get another ImportError!
Please advice.Is it the way of installation thats problematic?

Comment: From your stack track can we infer that you are trying to do this under Windows? You should edit your question to include this information, as it does influence the answers you will get.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like your pycrypto installation is broken or not installed.

Try to get a pycrypto for python2.6 installer here and try again after installing it.

> http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

Comment: If using latest Python 3.4, get pycrypto installer from here: https://github.com/axper/python3-pycrypto-windows-installer
 </shamelessplug>

Answer (score 4):

I tried Vijay's method,but it doesn't work.

I use the method on 'http://kmdarshan.com/blog/?p=3208',it works:

1. Goto to http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Downloads and download the pycrypto package .exe for windows/python2.5. This is needed for running paramiko.
2. Next, download the paramiko package from http://www.lag.net/paramiko/.
3. Unzip paramiko to a temporary folder, better if you unzip it to the folder where python is installed.
4. Go into the folder for paramiko.
5. Open command prompt and see to it that you have python set as the environment variable.
6. Run this command python setup.py install
7. You will get a series of lines of compilation. Just make sure you dont have any error in them. If you have any errors you will need to re compile them again.
8. Just be be sure everything is alright import paramiko in your program and see.
9. FYI: paramiko is used for ssh..and so on.

Answer (score 3):

1. Download paramiko for windows. You get the zip file:
   www.lag.net/paramiko/
2. To build it you need the dependency package pycrypto. Again keep in mind you will need a matching version of pycrypto for your Python. This is a built version of Windows so no install is required. http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto
3. You could do an easy_install by downloading setuptools but I ran into some issues so I chose to download MinGW tool. This is again an installation and no build is required. http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Automated%20MinGW%20Installer/mingw-get-inst/mingw-get-inst-20110316/
4. Once you have pycrypto and MinGW installed on your windows machine, just browse to the folder where you extracted the paramiko module from the zip file and issue this command:

   python setup.py build --compiler=mingw32 bdist_wininst

TADA! You are all set to use ssh on your windows machine with Python.

Answer (score 2):

I have installed paramiko onto 64bit Windows 7 successfully:

1. Install Python2.7
2. Download 64bit PyCrypto installation package from: http://www.dragffy.com/posts/ython-pycrypto-2-4-1-32-and-64-bit-windows-32x64-amdintel-installers
3. Download paramiko package from: http://www.lag.net/paramiko/
4. extract paramiko package
5. start a command line terminal from the extracted paramiko package, run
   "python setup.py install"

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to install Paramiko for Python 3.3.2 on Windows XP. I followed [the instructions here](http://queforum.com/python/436607-python-install-paramiko-windows.html)

After I downloaded all programs on the list for my Python version, Paramiko starts without problems.

1. Install python-2.7.3.amd64.msi
2. Install pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
3. Install setuptools-1.4.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
4. Install pip-1.4.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
5. Download and extract https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/archive/master.zip

Comment: Please do not post link-only answers. Include the relevant steps in your answer. Also, in the future, please format your answer to make it as readable as possible. Furthermore, this question already has an accepted answer - please make sure you're really adding something that wasn't available before.

Comment: Another thing: Why do you install Python 2.7, when you're actually trying to use Python 3.3?

Comment: lethal-guitar thanks you for edit my post, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: I wrote programs name, but people can find version of library and platform without my assistance

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem does not seem to be a broken Crypto install but a slightly different one. After installing paramiko and crypto with easy_install on windows I do have crypto installed but not Crypto. I installed the package PyCrypt (which gave an error because I didn't have a C compiler before I installed visual studio express)

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Crypto package you downloaded doesn't have AES...

you should try doing the following:

```
import Crypto
import Crypto.Util
import Crypto.Cipher
```

if any of those fail then you still need to make sure pycrypto is installed (see the link from S.Mark [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto)), otherwise Paramiko might not depend on having AES (even though there is a test for that)

Answer (score 0):

It seems PyCrypto uses a c-compiler(which is inherently present on the Linux system - gcc). 
Also, somewhere on the PyCrypto readme.txt file says, it needs to be 'build' first, before doing an 'install'
On Linux, I build it first and then ran 'install' command on it and was successfully installed.

Answer (score 0):

I searched for a long time looking for a solution to this problem.  I'm running Windows 7  64-bit and python 2.7.  None of the above solutions worked for me.

[this one did](http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/)

Don't forget to include the C++ compiler when you download the Microsoft SDK, it wasn't checked by default.

I downloaded the pycrypto 2.5 source to do the compile and the paramiko 2.3, things work well.

Comment: When you provide an external link as your answer you should also copy or summarize the relevant bits into your answer, in case the site you have linked is modified or no longer available later on.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very precise answer:

Step 1: Go to **https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko**

Step 2: Download the zip file, and extract it

Step 3: Move into the folder and run **python setup.py install**

You are done!

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem on my mac and the way I solved it was by simply just renaming the "crypto" directory to the "Crypto". I already had the paramiko and ssh installed in it. They both work perfectly fine now. However, this may or may not work for some one but this is just a simple thought on getting the ways around this problem.

[image: Renaming crypto to Crypto]

Answer (score 0):

just try

```
pip install paramiko
```

if this shows error, then

```
pip install cryptography
pip install paramiko
```