# Check if a python script is running on remote machine

Tags: windows, python-2.7, command-line, taskmanager

I am running a python script on say machine A. Is there any way to know if the python script is running or not from another machine B from command line? I tried getting the process list from the task manager. But it does not show any information regarding this script though it is running( it only showed cmd through which the script is executing ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be a three step process. Step 1 is only required because you are Windows. If you're Mac or Linux, they already come with Step 1 completed for you. Otherwise, this is completely cross-platform capable.

1) You need to remotely connect from Machine A to Machine B. One extremely popular way of doing this is SSH, which can be installed on Machine A and Machine B. The recommended way to do this is with FreeSSHd, which has been very well documented here: https://serverfault.com/questions/8411/what-is-a-good-ssh-server-to-use-on-windows

2) Install the paramiko SSH library for Python. This will allow you to connect to another machine, and execute any arbitrary command line command. On windows, you just need to install the binaries for paramiko and pycrypto/openssl. This also is well documented on SO here: [installing paramiko on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964658/installing-paramiko-on-windows)

3) Decide how you want to harvest the process list. There are several ways which are well documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489/how-do-you-list-all-processes-on-the-command-line-in-windows

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to do it this way :)