# python - terminate current ssh connection

Tags: python, ssh, ip

I have a python script on a machine.

I could run it from both **ssh connection** and the **console** of the machine.

Because the script changes some IP config stuff, I want to disconnect the ssh before doing the IP changing - that way the ssh won't hang and will be closed properly before the IP changes.

**So** - is there a way in python to check if the script is ran from ssh? and if so to close the ssh?

Comment: if you know the machine you're sshing to, you can check the hostname :)

Comment: if you close the ssh connection won't the python script stop or remain on the ssh machine?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19762162/check-if-a-python-script-is-running-on-remote-machine)

Comment: thanks for your answers. and is there a way to close all current ssh connections? regardless if I am working from a ssh or from the console. I want to terminate all ssh connections before changing the ip

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Linux machine, but tested on a Mac. If you issue a `who am i` command and see an IP address, you are on an ssh connection. If not, you are at the console. This answer is based on the following [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/187712/how-to-determine-if-im-logged-in-via-ssh).

On the console:

```
$ who am i
hai      ttys000  Dec 23 13:00
```

On ssh connection:

```
$ who am i
hai      ttys001  Jan  4 07:41  (192.168.1.19)
```

With this information, it is a matter of running the command from Python and parse the output.

## Update

Another method is to check for the presence of the environment variable SSH_CLIENT or SSH_TTY, according to the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh) here.

Comment: thanks for your answer. and is there a way to close all current ssh connections? regardless if I am working from a ssh or from the console. I want to terminate all ssh connections before changing the ip

Answer (score 0):

If you run the command `pkill --signal HUP sshd`. It should kill all ssh connections.

Then if you import `os` and use `os.system()` you could terminate all ssh connections from python.

```py
import os 

os.system("pkill --signal HUP sshd")
```