# Install paramiko on Windows

Tags: python, pip, paramiko, easy-install, pycrypto

OK. I read [installing paramiko on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964658/installing-paramiko-on-windows).

All mentioned methods simply do not work.

Authors have different environments with different components/libraries installed. Or may be they don't test their solutions before posting an answer :)

I removed all python versions and libs from my machine (Windows 8 x64) and tried to install python and paramiko from scratch.

**Method number 1 (FAILED)**

1. Install python-2.7.3.amd64.msi
2. Install pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
3. Download https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/archive/master.zip, unpack it.
4. Run setup.py install
5. Go to IDLE, run import paramiko.

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in
<module>
  import paramiko   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 65, in
<module>
    from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 45, in
<module>
   from paramiko.ecdsakey import ECDSAKey   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\ecdsakey.py", line 24, in
<module>
  from ecdsa import SigningKey, VerifyingKey, der, curves ImportError: No module named ecdsa
```

**Method number 2 (FAILED)**

1. Install python-2.7.3.amd64.msi
2. Install setuptools-1.4.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
3. Install pip-1.4.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe
4. pip install paramiko
5. Go to IDLE, run import paramiko.

Result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import paramiko
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 33, in <module>
    from paramiko import util
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\util.py", line 33, in <module>
    from paramiko.common import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\common.py", line 98, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
ImportError: No module named Crypto
```

**Method number 3 (SUCCESS)**

1. Install **python-2.7.3.amd64.msi**
2. Install **pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe**
3. Install **setuptools-1.4.2.win-amd64-py2.7.exe**
4. Install **pip-1.4.1.win-amd64-py2.7.exe**
5. Run **pip install ecdsa**
6. Download and extract https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/archive/master.zip
7. Run **setup.py install**
8. Open IDLE, run **import paramiko**

*Result: no errors*

Please, help me to find step-by-step algorithm for installing python and paramiko on clean windows 8 machine. Thanx.

UPD: Solution has been found.

Comment: Use [easy-install to install a binary PyCrypto installer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11405769/6364) and the rest of Paramiko should fall into place.

Answer (score 5):

For installing paramiko, Visual Basic Compiler is needed.

First download it from Microcsoft: [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=44266)

Open the paramiko directory and run     python setup.py install    . And it will download dependencies from internet; especially pycrypto and installation will be successful.

Comment: Your link is dead.

Comment: @user2284570, The link is probably updated, as it's not dead anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `pycrypto` dependency. `pip` is the easiest way:

```
pip install pycrypto
pip install paramiko
```

Alternatively, you can install from source, with:

```
easy_install ./
```

(See: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko)

Comment: 1) it won't be that easy on win. 2) he did install it with pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe (my guess is that is not correct one, but can't check now)

Comment: pycrypto is installed with pycrypto-2.6.win-amd64-py2.7.exe

Comment: Clearly OPs installation *cannot* find pycrypto, so something's messed up. Installing both via pip is the easiest way to make sure both are installed to the same place properly. Yes, even on windows.

Comment: @YuvalAdam PyCrypto is a C-extension, it's not so obvious task to compile it for a beginner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405549/how-do-i-install-pycrypto-on-windows

Comment: Worked for me on Win10 using python 3.6.0

Answer (score 2):

For windows users:

1. Install Python 2.7.11
2. Download and install pycrypto win-amd64-py2.7.exe
3. Now open a command prompt. If you have installed python at the following location:

   c:\Python27 then change directory and go to Scripts directory.
4. Now type the following command:

   pip install paramiko

[image]

That's it, you have successfully installed Paramiko.

Comment: Simple elegant solution.  I had to change the pycrypto package to fit my currently installed python version (3.4). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- For the first sequence you need to install 'ecdsa' with pip because paramiko compilation does not automatically resolve its dependencies (as your working solution)
- The second failed, as stated already, because you did not install pycrypto before running `pip install paramiko`. I would recommend to use this option rather than installing from source to enable easier upgrade path using pip. Also pip is the easiest to install using their standalone install script: `http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html`

Answer (score 0):

## Also, I faced with the following errors like:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -IC:\Python27-x86\include -IC:\Python27-x86\PC /Tcbuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release_openssl.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\build\temp.win32-2.7\Release_openssl.obj

_openssl.c

build\temp.win32-2.7\Release_openssl.c(423) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: **'openssl/opensslv.h'**: No such file or directory

error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

missed this file: **'openssl/opensslv.h'**

it will be happens because while installation paramiko/cryptography/pyOpenSSL packages, they all needed distribution package of **OpenSSL-Win32** with ***.lib** and headers files like: **openssl\opensslv.h**

so, after installation appropriate OpenSSL app. version, took from here: 
http://code.x2go.org/releases/binary-win32/3rd-party/Win32OpenSSL/

and copied all headers from C:\OpenSSL-Win32\include\openssl*.* to C:\Pyhton27\inclide*.*

and copied all libs from C:\OpenSSL-win32\lib to C:\Python27\Lib*.*

paramiko package was installed successfully. !
I hope it will be helpful somebody.:) 
good luck:)