# Open SSH and Submit Commands To It

Tags: python, ssh

I am attempting to open a SSH connection to a Linux console. I want to be able to submit commands to the SSH after opening it (such as ls, cd, etc). How can I do this?

I am using the subprocess to begin the SSH connection.

subprocess.Popen(["C:\ssh\ssh.exe", "SERVER"]);

Comment: I would assume there is a native ssh implementation in python.

Comment: I was originally going to do it through SSH, but I think using a native ssh would be smarter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this at the process level, which is hard and error-prone, my advice is using [`paramiko`](http://www.paramiko.org/) or the higher-level [`fabric`](http://www.fabfile.org/).

Fabric contains a lot of helper functions for common automation tasks, such as copying files

Comment: Is there a built-in python library that I would be able to use (such as System.XML)? I am connecting to the Linux machine from a Windows environment.

Comment: @user2970916 as far as I know, no. Even if you use `paramiko`, [using SSH from windows is a though proposition](http://www.paramiko.org/faq.html). Consider running your program in a more friendly operating system if you want to interact with unix systems.

Comment: I wish I could...but it's a company system that's been setup. Maybe I will have to stick with using subprocess....or maybe another language.

Comment: @user2970916 Any other language will have the same problem, I think. Try [installing paramiko on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964658/installing-paramiko-on-windows) and see how it goes - it's better than reinventing the wheel. Installing a VM may be a good option too