# Install Python module paramiko on windows

Tags: python, paramiko

I have been trying to install **paramiko** module on windows without success. I have been getting  errors related to Visual C++ compiler missing. Is it possible to install **paramiko** without having to go through compile process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installing paramiko on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964658/installing-paramiko-on-windows)

Comment: Another possible (and perhaps better) duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538685/install-paramiko-on-windows

Comment: Neither one of those is a duplicate of what he's describing, though I would guess the solution in the second case would probably work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20538685/install-paramiko-on-windows) this is what I would suggest (assuming you already have >=python-2.7.9 installed, if not, upgrade, 2.7.9 comes with pip, pre 2.7.9 doesn't):

1. Get the appropriate pycrypto whl file (based on python version and win32/win_amd64). I've found some available [here](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/pycrypto-2.6.1/) (can't vouch for the site as I don't use python on windows much).
2. Run `pip install pycrypto-stuff.whl` (in a command prompt window in the directory where you've saved the pycrypto whl file).
3. Run `pip install paramiko` (in a command prompt, but can be in w/e folder you like).

That should do the trick. In general a simple `pip install package_name` would work, but `pycrypto` does not provide a wheel file (binary package), therefore you have to build it. By the sound of it you don't have Visual C++ installed (or not the right version, it only works for one, I don't recall which), `pycrypto` needs an extension package built to use the system crypto libraries, which is why the source package isn't working.

Comment: Thank you.. This is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working by installing the following packages using pip.

`pip install bcrypt cryptography pynacl paramiko`

These were the packages my Linux install used as prerequisites, so they should work on windows as well.